# Write-eventlog fails when running from task scheduler

Tags: powershell, scripting, permissions, domaincontroller

So I've been looking for a solution to this problem for the last 2 days, here is the breakdown. i am simply trying to write an event log to the system log on one of my domain controllers, when i run my script manually using ISE or normal PowerShell it creates the log on the remote machine with 0 issue. When i run the script in a task schedule using a service account i know has permissions to write to the system log it fails, it also fails when i use my credentials to run it in task schedule even though it works when i run it manually.

here is the script

```
Write-eventlog -computername dc1 -logname system -source "script_output_events_test1" -entrytype warning -eventid 45912 -message "test"``
```

super simple nothing complicated, all i want is to create the event log so our event monitoring service gets notified.

one thing i do need to mention is while troubleshooting i put a out-file command in there to see if its even running the script and can confirm it created the file i put on there when running from the task, so i know its running the script from task scheduler but its not completing the write-eventlog command for some reason.

Comment: I've just tested your example code on one of my test networks (substituting the source for something valid on my machines) and it appears to work okay in my case. It's worth adding `Start-Transcript -Path <LogFileNameHere>` to the beginning of your script to see if you capture any errors?

Comment: Hmm when i add a start-transcript  i get this excuse the format
"TerminatingeError(write-eventlog): "attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
write-eventlog : attempted to perform an unauthorized operation." 
at C:\scripts\bitlockerlogoutputest.ps1:4 char: 1
+ write-eventlog -computername 172.22.200.5 -logname system -source"SD ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CATEGORY INFO : notspecified : (:) [write-eventlog, unauthorizedaccessexception
+fullyqualifiederrorid : system.unauthorized accessexception, microsoft.powershell.commands.writeeventlog]"

Comment: Definitely sounds like a permissions problem then, even though you've verified the script using the same account manually. Unlikely to fix, but is the task configured to run with the ***Run with highest privileges *** option ticked? As a workaround, you could attempt to use the `Invoke-Command -ComputerName <FQDN> -ScriptBlock {<CommandsHere>}` (assuming you've got remoting enabled, devices in the same domain and the account running the script has relevant permissions)

Comment: yep the task is set to run with highest permissions, also tried that work around and can confirm it works when running the script manually but when running the task in task scheduler it doesn't write to the event log